# How to open a file in default text editor in onAction event method (Headless Graphics environment)

Tags: java, javafx

I am trying to open a file on button click event in JavaFx using this.

```
java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().open(File f);
```

but it is giving **java.awt.HeadlessException at java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop** exception.

Is there any way to open a file in headless environment?.

Comment: You have to use like this . if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
        desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
      }

Comment: Can you try to use and see. java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().edit(file); use this instead of open and let us know.

Comment: edit(file) didn't work as getDesktop() is throwing headless exception.

Comment: First you have to use like this if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) { desktop = Desktop.getDesktop(); }  and inside you can try to edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One try would be to disable headless for a while, open the file and finally enable it again. Something like:

```
System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "true"); // assume it is enabled somewhere
File desktop = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "Desktop");
File text = new File(desktop, "a.txt");
System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "false");
Desktop.getDesktop().open(text);
System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "true");
```

**However** sometimes `System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "false");` is not enough to disable headless property. One *dirty* solution would be to change its value via `reflect`.

```
System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "true"); // assume it is enabled somewhere
File desktop = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "Desktop");
File text = new File(desktop, "a.txt");
setHeadless(false);
Desktop.getDesktop().open(text);
setHeadless(true);
Desktop.getDesktop().open(text);
```

with `setHeadless` method:

```
private static void setHeadless(boolean enabled) {
    try {
        Field defaultHeadlessField = java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.class.getDeclaredField("defaultHeadless");
        defaultHeadlessField.setAccessible(true);
        defaultHeadlessField.set(null, enabled);
        Field headlessField = java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment.class.getDeclaredField("headless");
        headlessField.setAccessible(true);
        headlessField.set(null, enabled);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

---

Second try (and more "forcing") would be to open it through command line. For **Windows** OS (i do not know about **Linux**/**MacOS**) would be:

```
File desktop = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "Desktop");
File text = new File(desktop, "a.txt");

ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder();
processBuilder.command("cmd.exe", "/c", text.getAbsolutePath()).start();
```

Comment: Thanks @George Z. for you response. but
System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "false"); is not disabling headless.

Comment: @ZeeshanShahid I was 50-50 that i will not work for you. Post edited, check if it works for you.

Comment: I have troubles with the first method - InaccessibleObjectException is thown (which means Java does not allow touching its internals). The second way works, but it requires checking for OS